# Matlab plots black border

Tags: matlab, plot, border

I have three different plots inside a loop: two plots have border, but one doesn't:

[image: results]

I want all of them to have a black border. I tried to make it by using [`box`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/box.html) but the problem persists.

```
hold on
figure(1),plot((delta1),Sref1,'*','Color',colors(i,:));title('Frequency [500MHz-1GHz]')
gcf=figure(1);
set(gcf,'Position', [0 0 290 245]);
hold off

hold on 
figure(2),plot((delta2),Sref2,'*','Color',colors(i,:));title('Frequency [1GHz-1.5GHz]')
gcf=figure(2);
set(gcf,'Position', [0 0 290 245]);
hold off 

hold on
figure(3),plot((delta3),Sref3,'*','Color',colors(i,:));title('Frequency [1.5GHz-2GHz]')
gcf=figure(3);
set(gcf,'Position', [0 0 290 245]);

hold off
```

Comment: Can you post your code that generates these plots?

Comment: Are you using the `opengl` figure renderer by any chance? If I remember correctly, there is a bug related to `box on` with opengl as renderer: http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-5TS5P4/index.html . btw your code could be simplified as: `figure('pos',[. . . .]); plot(x,y,..); title('..')` for each one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add `box on` before the first `hold off` line.

This code worked for me (Matlab 2012b):

```
hold on
figure(1),plot(1:10);title('Frequency [500MHz-1GHz]')
gcf=figure(1);
set(gcf,'Position', [0 0 290 245]);
box on
hold off

hold on 
figure(2),plot(1:10);title('Frequency [1GHz-1.5GHz]')
gcf=figure(2);
set(gcf,'Position', [0 0 290 245]);
hold off 

hold on
figure(3),plot(1:10);title('Frequency [1.5GHz-2GHz]')
gcf=figure(3);
set(gcf,'Position', [0 0 290 245]);

hold off
```